# Angular - Service Component

Tags: angular, components

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

Getting the above error message. Need help in this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GlobalDataSummary } from '../models/gloabl-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {

  private globalDataUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-01-2021.csv'
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  getGlobalData(){
    return this.http.get(this.globalDataUrl, {responseType :'text'}).pipe(
      map(result=>{
        let data: GlobalDataSummary[] = [];
        let raw = {}
        let rows = result.split('\n');
        rows.splice(0 , 1);
        //console.log(rows);
        rows.forEach(row=>{
          let cols = row.split(/,(?=\S)/)
          
          let cs = {
            country : cols[3],
            confirmed : +cols[7],
            deaths : +cols[8],
            recovered : +cols[9],
            active : +cols[10],
          };
          let temp = raw[cs.country];
          if(temp)
          {
            temp.active = cs.active + temp.active
            temp.confirmed = cs.confirmed + temp.confirmed
            temp.deaths = cs.deaths + temp.deaths
            temp.recovered = cs.recovered + temp.recovered
            raw[cs.country] = temp;
          }else{
            raw[cs.country] = cs;
          }
          

          
          
        })
        
        
        return Object.values(raw);
        
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are assigning the values to raw dynamically whose type is not explicitly marked. This can be fixed by explicitly marking raw with any type. Change

```
let raw = {}
```

to

```
 let raw:any = {}
```

This would be a quick fix. A better fix to use proper typings. Create types for the raw object like this

```
interface Raw {
   [key: string]: CS;
}
```

Here we are creating a type for objects which will have string keys and vales will be of CS type. CS is what you are trying to assign to raw. You can name it as per your choice. Below is the type for CS.

```
interface CS {
    country: string;
    confirmed : number,
    deaths : number,
    recovered : number,
    active : number,
}
```

Assign the type like this:

```
let raw: Raw = {};
```

// This won't fail. This is just an example that is should work.

```
raw['India'] = {
     country: 'India',
    confirmed : 22,
    deaths : 0,
    recovered : 22,
    active : 0,
}
```

Comment: Also, if you know that `result` was a string use `map((result:string)=>{...}`